# Open source project home page

Tags: c#, open-source, project

I've created a software that I want to be able to market. I'd like to be able to post it on forums etc and for that I need a home page.

Is there any open source C# project home pages that you can use?

The functionality I'm looking for is like adding new versions (perhaps a version control from the software), downloading and user guides. So what I want is pretty basic: I want to be able to upload and let the users download.

I've written this on my own as well but I guess that if there are open source projects that have done this they're probably better.

This can't be such a rare problem so please lead me to some resources so that I can create my page and publish my software! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/), [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net), [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/), [Savannah](http://savannah.nongnu.org), and [CodePlex](http://codeplex.com/) (among others) provide this service.

Comment: Ok but, are there any projects like a framework to make a home page of software? Those positions which you have enumerated are services which give opportunity to upload project on their storage. But what if someone wants to store his project on his own server? And especially if software is not open source.

Comment: @nosbor, two big ones are [Savane](http://gna.org/projects/savane/) (which runs Savannah) and [FusionForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FusionForge), both descendants of the original open source SourceForge software.  See also [Comparison of open source software hosting facilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Free_Software_Hosting_Facilities).

Comment: Oh, I missed [Launchpad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchpad_(website)), which is now free software under the GNU AGPL.

Comment: I saw that you need to have linux to install Savane or FF. So do you know any for windows?

Comment: @nosbor, not that I know of.  But maybe we're looking at it the wrong way.  If your software is proprietary, maybe you just want a [Content Management System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems) for the user guides and such with a link to download your latest executable.